# Trigger function error: Record "old" not yet assigned

Tags: postgresql, trigger, functions

I'm new to trigger functions and trying to work this out. I have looked for solutions in the documentation and applied those, but still something is wrong here. My aim is to show error an message when inserting into this specific column.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_f() 
    RETURNS TRIGGER
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $$
    BEGIN
    IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN 
    IF (OLD.col1 != NEW.col1) THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Editing not allowed';
        END IF;
        END IF;
        RETURN NEW;
        END;
    $$;

    CREATE TRIGGER test_t
    Before insert on schema.table
    For each row execute procedure test_f();

    Insert into schema.table(col1)
    VALUES
    ('test');
```

(I'm aware there are questions like mine already however those haven't helped in my case.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of an `INSERT`, there is no previous version of the row, so the `OLD` variable is unassigned.

See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-DML-TRIGGER):

> `OLD`
>
> Data type `RECORD`; variable holding the old database row for `UPDATE`/`DELETE` operations in row-level triggers. This variable is null in statement-level triggers and for `INSERT` operations.

Comment: Ah of course, that makes sense! Must have mixed it up when trying out different solutions. Thanks